# If a $\{a_n\}$ diverges, so $a_n \rightarrow + \infty$, how to find sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that $\sum |b_n|<\infty$ but $\sum |a_n||b_n|$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If we are given any sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ diverges, so $a_n \rightarrow + \infty$, how can we find a sequence $\{b_n\}$ such that $\sum |b_n|$ converges but $\sum |a_n||b_n|$ diverges?

I want to use this fact in another problem but don't immediately see how to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pick a subsequence such that $a_{n_k} > k$, and then let $b_{n_k} = 1/k^2$, and $b_n = 0$ if $n$ is not an index in that subsequence.

Comment: aha this is quite easy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assume contrary that for all $(b_n )\in \ell_1 $ the series  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } a_n b_n $$ is convergent.
Define $$T_n :\ell_1 \to \mathbb{R} $$ $$T_n (b) =\sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j .$$
The functionals $T_n $ are linear and continuous and $$\lim_{n\to \infty} T_n b$$ exists for any $b\in \ell_1 $ moreover  $||T_n ||=\sup_{1\leq k\leq n} |a_k |$. Thus by Banach -Steinhaus Theorem $$\exists_{M>0}\forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}} ||T_n||\leq M$$ but this contradicts to the fact that $$a_n \to\infty.$$